# Revert to Utopic Stack on 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, kernel, suspend

I bounced from perfect 14.04.1, to Freya, to 15.04 and lastly 14.04.3.

I couldn't find 14.04.1 on the Ubuntu website. Once I left Freya, I started having issues, every time X was started, there was a 50% chance the mouse and touchpad wont reconnect and I cant do anything other than force shut down. When I press the power button the restart window appears however I can't select anything and I cant drop to any TTY.

This not only happens on boot, it happens when resuming from suspend, which is dissappointing, my Lenovo u410 worked perfectly since 14.04 and the upgrade to 3.16 was flawless.

This leads me to believe my problem is in kernel 3.19, I however also tried 4.0.2 from ubuntu mainline on 15.04 and still had issues.

I tried
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg-xserver-input-all

and was unsuccessful.

If I could get my almost all intel computer to work as perfect on 3.19+ as it did on 3.16 I'd be willing to stay. However as of right now I want to install the HWE Stack from 14.04.1 on 14.04.3.

Edit:

I installed the lts utopic kernel and the issues persists.

I believe the issue resides in init or lightdm. I really dont like forcing shutdowns so frequently.

Does 14.04(1) use an older version of lightDM? Perhaps I could try that. I dont think the issue is upstart, because it occurred first for me on systemd in 15.04

EDIT:

I installed the full 14.04.1 stack and rebooted, the issue persists.
Kernel 3.16, I ran lightdm --version and found 1.10.5.

I found the 14.04.1 in old-releases on ubuntu.com. Installed 14.04.1, lightdm 1.10.1 works perfect. Setup my desktop as I like and installed the HWE for 14.04.2 and kernel 3.16. I rebooted and the issue came back, after a few boots I got to my desktop and checked to find lightdm 1.10.5 was installed in the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can downgrade only the kernel. Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

Then start synaptic and remove 3.19 kernel image and headers. Then reboot.
This is probably the kernel issue.

If this does not help, then downgrade xorg by

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Comment: Wont I need to drop the xorg, mesa, etc? I thought those were upgraded in the HWE.

Comment: It is more likely that the problem is with the kernel. Try that first.

Comment: Kernel 3.16 didn't fix the problem. I may need to rollback more. If it's not likely to be LightDM, could it be x init?

Comment: Are you sure you booted with 3.16. What does `uname -r` show?

Comment: I'm very sure, and I checked with the same command, showed 3.16-ubuntu-generic.

I dont think it's kernel related at all, the keyboard and mouse work until lightdm comes up. It's either init or lightdm

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Had a bad problem with the lts graphic stack on intel card and this worked to have my desktop back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find cd images of old/unsupported releases of Ubuntu [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/release/), so can choose a 14.04.1 release, or even 14.04 ,  if you'd like to start from a known installation.

There's also the option of manually downgrading your kernel by installing a previous kernel, as Pilot6 mentions. (too quick!)

Comment: Thank you, it's a really roundabout way to find that page through the hyperlinks.
I installed 14.04.1, as long as I dont install the HWE for Utopic or Vivid I'm golden.

I find so far a direct coorelation with the lightDM version, I reported a bug while atop lightdm 1.10.5 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1482684

Comment: Okay, I was wrong, installed GDM from default ppas and the issue persists.
I could I get log files without a keyboard? Could I SSH in from my phone?